# Deploying symfony project in bitnami image on amazon ec2

Tags: symfony, bitnami

The symfony is in /Frameworks folder, and the root path is in Apache2/htdocs/, how to deploy a symfony project? Do I need to copy symfony folder to htdocs, condisdering Apache2/htdocs/ like localhost/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your Symfony folders in the htdocs folder and set Apache to serve from Symfony's 'web' folder which contains the app.php file.
You need to do some Apache configuration here, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423983/symfony2-how-to-deploy-in-subdirectory-apache)