# How to make a Symfony2 Bundle Live on a Website

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have been looking around for a bit with no luck finding an answer. I am new to Symfony2 and spent the last couple weeks installing it on my website's server, making a bundle and building all the pages, and testing it out with its app_dev.php urls. I'm now ready to make it public on my site, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Basically, I want to activate the bundles so instead of having to go to website/symfony/web/app_dev.php/Page, I can just go to website/Page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thats not really a Symfony issues and it depends very much on your environment (mostly what webserver you are using). What you have to do is make the web folder of the symfony project your root folder (aka, where right now is the symfony folder) and move all other folder within symfony folder one level up. So lets say you have your httpdocs or www folder as your root folder, you have to copy the contents of symfony/web in that folder and move everything else from symfony folder one level above httpdocs folder. That being said, probably there is a lot more configuration that goes on into it. Here are a couple of resources to get you started:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html

[Symfony2: How to deploy in subdirectory (Apache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423983/symfony2-how-to-deploy-in-subdirectory-apache)

Remember that in live mode you should be accessing app.php and not app_dev.php...

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do it by adding those lines to an .htaccess file on the root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then the original .htaccess file in the web directory takes care of the rest.

Comment: Is this still valid for Symfony 2.5?