# How to deploy Symfony2 on a shared-hosting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony, shared-hosting

I want to access my symfony app in production env (http://www.sample.com/amateur1/web/app.php) from this url http://www.sample.com/amateur1.

To do that I moved the .htacces file to http://www.sample.com/amateur1/.htaccess with this contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /web/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I go to http://www.sample.com/amateur1 shows a 404 Error, and *prod.log* isn't written.

I also used `RewriteBase /amateur1/web/` because I don't know If *RewriteBase* path is relative to the *DocumentRoot* of the server, Or from the path where the *.htaccess* file is located. Also tried `/amateur1` and `/amateur1/` as RewriteBase due to this answer [Symfony2: How to deploy in subdirectory (Apache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423983/symfony2-how-to-deploy-in-subdirectory-apache)

With the three try's, The Exceptions page appears unstyled, and not loading any image. But then I get the following error in prod.log file:

```
[2013-02-15 02:06:47] request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /amateur1/" (uncaught exception) at /home/u105859802/public_html/amateur1/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 5121 [] []
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you check config.php? It shows you missing requirements

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your configuration, apache uses `public_html` as the document root

If Symfony2 is installed in directory `/home/u105859802/public_html/amateur1`, the Symfony public directory to serve is `/home/u105859802/public_html/amateur1/web/`

You should use

```
RewriteBase /amateur1/web/
```

**But beware, it is not safe**
**You have to protect your symfony directories! (configuration is accessible)**

Why don't you try moving your symfony files in your private area ?
You can rename the Symfony web directory to `public_html`

See [how to do that in documentation cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory)

So, my recommendation structure looks like below :

- /home/u105859802/

  - vendor
  - src
  - app
  - bin
  - **public_html** (web by default in symfony2)  **<- the only public directory**

Comment: Do you mean to move my sf dir to */home/u105859802/amateur1/* being a sibling (brother) of */home/u105859802/public_html/* And putting into */public_html/* dir the contents of my */web/* directoy. Then *public_html/.htaccess* file should just redirect everything to app without *RewriteBase* or being just *RewriteBase /* right ? this way `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]`.

Comment: I can't try it now, let me try it before accepting the answer. Thank you for this useful info !

Answer (score 0):

In most of the shared hosting, you can't override Apache settings in that case may need to wright a redirection rule in .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^projectName/ /projectName/web/app.php/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

this is the rule I used in my project . 
You may need to provide full paths to your assets other ways they will not get loaded .