# Remove web/app.php in Symfony2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

My server has the following directory structure

```
/srv
   /www
      /site.com
         /symfonysite
         /Other Drupal hosted site files
```

when I go to `site.com` my drupal site opens up and I want to be able to access my symfony site on `site.com/symfonysite` instead of `site.com/symfonysite/web/app.php`

I created an **.htaccess** file inside `/symfonysite` shown below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /billing/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

But this only gets rid of the app.php part, i.e. `site.com/symfonysite/web` opens my symfony site and `site.com/symfonysite` gives `No route found for "GET /symfonysite/"` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14893169/330267

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its the beauty of symfony that it is highly configurable.
You can achieve what you are looking for by following the simple 4 steps:

1. Create a directory(say project) and put all the content of **symfonysite** there. You can put this directory any where you like. For simplicity we are going to create the directory in your **symfonysite** dir.
2. Move all content of your **symfonysite/web** to **symfonysite**
3. Edit the **app.php** and or **app_dev.php** to modify two line as follow:

   > $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
   >   require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

   to

   > $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/project/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
   >   require_once __DIR__.'/project/app/AppKernel.php';
4. Edit **composer.json** file to update the value of  **"symfony-web-dir": "web"** and change it to

   > "symfony-web-dir": "../",

Your modified directory structure may look like:

```
/srv
   /www
      /site.com
         /symfonysite
              /project
         /Other Drupal hosted site files
```

NB: For security reason symfony suggest to expose only the web directory to a web accessible path. You can put the project directory any where you like. Just need to update the path as per your locations.
To give this set-up a little more security you can put a .htaccess file in the project directory

.htaccess

> Deny from all

Enjoy!!

Comment: You can find reference documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `/srv/www/site.com/symfonysite/web` the document root of the project. 
This can't be done with .htaccess so you need to change apache virtual host config. 
This usually lives in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yourserver.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourserver.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/site.com/symfonysite/web
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure how rackspace sites work, maybe best to open a support ticket with them if you are unable to change these settings. I head they have  Fanatical Support :P

Comment: this doesnt seem to address the issue, the OP site.com already has a document root of /srv/www/site.com. changing that will make the drupal site inaccessible on that domain. You should simply configure symfony as xiisea suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach IMHO is to use symlinks. In the site.com/web/content directory you need to run `ln -s symfonysite/web sitesymfony`. It will create symlink `sitesymfony` in your web-root that points to `/site.com/web/content/symfonysite/web` folder. Then your site.com/sitesymfony will call app.php from site.com/symfonysite/web

Comment: I'm using Rackspace Cloud Sites and Symlinks aren't supported unfortunately.

Comment: UPDATE: Using Rackspace Cloud Server now